# Do I have to remove asbestos tiles in my house before applying epoxy floor coating?

Tags: repair, tile, asbestos, epoxy

I have the old style VCT asbestos tiles in my den and want to install an epoxy coating. Do I have to pay someone to remove the tiles first? Is there an alternative?

Comment: There are quite a few discussions on this topic already. Did you give the search a try? See also RELATED at right.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. You do not have to hire an asbestos removal company for this. I purchased my epoxy from epoxyplus.com.  They told they always recommend that their customers put a product called perfect primer down over their old tiles or glue floor  (as long as the tiles were not loose), then apply their epoxies on top of that.  I took their advice and it was easy and came out great.

Comment: Your answer doesn't support your claim that an abatement company is not required. You should revise to explain how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: I think the point was that there's no reason to remove the asbestos - you can simply cover it with the epoxy.  This doesn't get the asbestos out of the house, but there is no safety issue until someone decides to remove both the epoxy and the tile.

Comment: What should be added here is: If you **do** remove the tiles then you should hire a professional asbestos removal company to do the work - i.e., asbestos **removal** is not considered a DIY job.

Comment: Asbestos removal hype is more than a bit over blown. If allowed in your jurisdiction it can easily be a diy job we did it for decades with no protection. But the question was asking if it was coated could it be overlaid. In fact it could be overlaid without being coated.