# Applying PerfectPrimer overlay then epoxy over VOC tile instead of abating/replacing

Tags: asbestos, epoxy, voc

I found this question on the site but was looking for some more details. I am hoping someone can tell me a little more about the experience with the PerfectPrimer overlay as this was recommended to me as well. Someone replied to a another question said they used Perfect Primer and then used Epoxyplus product and it worked well.  I am hoping that person or someone else who used it can let me know if they found it pretty easy to apply and is your epoxy floor holding up well over it? I really would be great to just cover over my VOC tiles instead of the major expense messy removal/asbestos abatement, this would be such a relief!!

Comment: I guess you're talking about [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/136759/43874), but I'm not sure...  Either way, this sounds like a shopping/product recommendation question and that's not a good fit for the site.  We usually talk in general about how to do a job rather than specifically mention brand names and how to use that one brand.

Comment: Follow the MFG instructions, some types do not require a primer.

Comment: VOC?  Do you mean VCT?